# Read before Upsert in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, upsert

i am confused how Azure Cosmos DB "UpsertDocumentAsync" C# API works.
Looks that the object is updated if you first read it:

```
var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, "docId"), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("pk") });
var upsertOrder = response.Resource;
var upsertOrder = new Measurements { Id = "docId" , value = 3243};
upsertOrder.SetPropertyValue("value", 5678);
response = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionLink, upsertOrder);
```

If instead i directly create an object:

```
 var upsertOrder = new Measurements { Id = "docId" , value = 3243};
 response = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionLink, upsertOrder);
```

this create a new object!! Am i really constrained to read the doc before patching it??

**EDIT**
I understand i need to add the partitionKey too. So it does not create a new object anymore BUT it sets all the non-passed field to NULL. This is not a patch behavior! So am i correct i need to pass all fields anyway?

thanks lot to shade lights here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync doesn't update, it inserts duplicated ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776123/idocumentclient-upsertdocumentasync-doesnt-update-it-inserts-duplicated-ids)

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken thanks. I understand i need to add the partitionKey too. So it does not create a new object anymore BUT it sets all the non-passed field to NULL. This is not a patch behavior! So am i correct i need to pass all fields anyway?

Comment: The DocumentDB sdk that microsoft provides is a bit weird with how it handles POCO objects and crud operations. I would recommend using [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) which handles things like this replication problem. Disclaimer: I'm the author of Cosmonaut

Comment: @Elfocrash thanks. So, you confirm CosmosDB API for upsert do not support a realy patch behaviour?

Comment: It does but you have to either change the Measurements class `Id` to lowecase `id` in order for it to map automatically to the documents the cosmosdb api is creating OR use the `[JsonProperty("id")]` attribute on the Id property. It has many small things like this, that's why I suggested the package.

Comment: well although not showed above my code already contains the property value:  public class Measurements
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; } ...

Comment: Even changing the Measurement class `Id` to lower case `id` does not help!

Answer (score 3):

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document

As you can see the feature is planned but only got feedback on Mar 5, 2018 so it may be a while until delivery.

For the moment you can either read the document, update it, then insert as you have stated - part of the reason document size is an important design choice, or you could also write a stored procedure to do this and use this do partial updates.